# Deploying a logback enabled spring boot app to Glassfish 4/Payara generates gigs of logging

Tags: spring-boot, logback, glassfish-4, java.util.logging, payara

When I attempt to deploy a Spring Boot app to Payara (Glassfish 4) I'm getting huge logs that eventually use up all my disk space.

The logging seem to be in some sort of recursive loop like this (see below).

Although I can get a deploy working by turning off logging for unknown.jul.logger I'd rather not have it attempt to log in the first place. Also shown is the logback config.

Any ideas as to what might be going on here ?

Some more info:

It's SLF4JBridgeHandler that's defining the unknown.jul.logger.

> 15:29:50.448000  INFO 1296 --- [ing output pump] unknown.jul.logger :
>   2017-01-24 15:29:50.421000  INFO 1296 --- [ing output pump]
>   unknown.jul.logger : 2017-01-24 15:29:50.399000  INFO 1296 --- [ing
>   output pump] unknown.jul.logger : 2017-01-24 15:29:50.378000  INFO
>   1296 --- [ing output pump] unknown.jul.logger : 2017-01-24
>   15:29:50.350000  INFO 1296 --- [ing output pump] unknown.jul.logger :
>   2017-01-24 15:29:50.328000  INFO 1296 --- [ing output pump]
>   unknown.jul.logger : 2017-01-24 15:29:50.307000  INFO 1296 --- [ing
>   output pump] unknown.jul.logger : 2017-01-24

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <!-- Defined variables etc. -->
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>

    <!-- overridden two properties -->
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}000){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%logger){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wex"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}000 %5p ${PID:- } --- [%t] %logger : %m%n%wex"/>

    <!--  copied from base.xml -->
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <jmxConfigurator/>

    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What are the reasons you are deploying a SpringBoot app on an application server, if you can run it from command line? Just interested, I don't know SpringBoot too much.

Comment: because that's the app server the company wants to deploy to....

Comment: I thought so :) Thanks for sharing. Does your app work if you run it as a standalone Spring Boot app, outside of Payara Server?

Comment: Yes it works fine. I suspect it's related to the following:

Spring boot includes org.slf4j:ul-to-slf4j to redirect JUL logging to slf4j, and then uses logback as the default logging API for slf4j. 

My guess is that when JUL logging gets redirected to slf4j and then logback, it's perhaps trying to log the fact that it's logging, and therefore goes into a recursive loop. I got 240 gigs of logging....

Perhaps normally the app outside of Payara isn't doing any JUL logging, but it is during the deploy to Payara. I'll try and get a minimal POM to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed that this is caused by the following:

This is caused by Payara highjacking console output and redirecting to a logger, which the logging bridges that Spring Boot supplies as dependencies will then pipe out to whatever unified logger you pick (e.g. logback). If logback is configured to log to the console it goes into a cycle of never ending logging.

The solution is to make sure logback doesn't log to the console.

Comment: commenting out logging to STOUT fixed the problem for me, so this answer can be accepted!